# Celery 4.3.0 - Send Signal To a Task Without Termination

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

On a celery service on CENTOS which runs a single task at a time, the termination of a task is simple:

`revoke(id, terminate=True, signal='SIGINT')`

However while the interrupt signal is being processed, the running task gets revoked. Then a new task - from the queue - starts on the node. This is troublesome. Two task are running at the same time on the node. The signal handling could take up to a minute.

The question is how a signal could be sent to a running task, without actually terminating the task in celery?
Or let's say is there any way to send a signal to a running task?

The assumption is user should be able to send a signal from a remote node. In other words user does not have access to list the running processes of the node.

Any other solution is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your goal.

Are you trying to kill the worker? if so, I guess you are talking about t "Warm shutdown", so you can send the SIGTEERM to the worker's [process](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/workers.html#process-signals). The running task will get a chance to finish but no new task will be added.

If you're just interested in revoking a specific task and keep using the same worker, can you share your celery configuration and the worker command? are you sure you're running with concurrency 1 ?

Comment: This is the question: The question is how a signal could be sent to a running task, without actually terminating the task in celery? Or let's say is there any way to send a signal to a running task?

Comment: @hpaknia I didn't understand that from the original question. Can you elaborate more? what would you like to notify your task with this signal?

Comment: Suppose I want to send a `SIGUSR1` signal to the running task. Task has a specific handler for different signals. The handler could stop the job. It could redeliver the job. It could power cycle (reboot) the node. Celery only gives an option to revoke + send a signal. My question is how a signal could be sent to the main process of a running job, without revoking the task.

Comment: what about https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.contrib.abortable.html#celery-contrib-abortable

Comment: We don't use databases: > Note
In order to abort tasks, there needs to be communication between the producer and the consumer. This is currently implemented through the database backend. Therefore, this class will only work with the database backends.